# EF6 CreateStoredProcedure with Table Type parameter

Tags: entity-framework-6

I would like to use the EF CreateStoredProcedure method in a code first migration class.
the 2nd parameter is a Func<> for the parameters. however this only contains SQL data types.

I would like to use this with my own Table Type.

Is there a solution for this, or i have to find another way?

Comment: EF does not support Table-Valued Parameters.

Comment: yeah, i thought, but thanks for the confirmation